# Merge two sets of array keys in order

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have multiple arrays and I'd like to get an array of just the keys, but ensure that the keys are kept in order.

The outcome of this project is that every element gets put in a row in a CSV. Now I want to get the label array as the first row in the sheet and each line should follow afterwards. Some arrays of data will have more detail, note `Label 3.x`

```
$aArr1 = array (
    'Label 1' => 'Value',
    'Label 2' => 'Value',
    'Label 3.1' => 'Value',
    'Label 4' => 'Value',
    'Label 5' => 'Value',
    'Label 6' => 'Value'
);

$aArr2 = array (
    'Label 1' => 'Value',
    'Label 2' => 'Value',
    'Label 3.1' => 'Value',
    'Label 3.2' => 'Value',
    'Label 3.3' => 'Value',
    'Label 4' => 'Value',
    'Label 5' => 'Value'
);

$aArr3 = array (
    'Label 1' => 'Value',
    'Label 2' => 'Value',
    'Label 3.1' => 'Value',
    'Label 3.2' => 'Value'
)

$aDesiredLabelArr = array (
    'Label 1',
    'Label 2',
    'Label 3.1',
    'Label 3.2',
    'Label 3.3',
    'Label 4',
    'Label 5',
    'Label 6'
);
```

My inputs are `$aArr1`, `$aArr2` & `$aArr3`. My desired output is `$aDesiredLabelArr`. I'm writing in PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: What about the key `Label 3` ?

Comment: are you looking for array of `keys` both pair of `keys` and `values` .... and  What about the key `Label 3 ?`

Comment: @Ayaou... good spot, not meant to be there :) But basically as and when any keys are added (in a foreach loop for example) they should be added into the `$aDesiredLabelArr` in the relevant position.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What have you attempted and where is it failing?

Comment: @nerdlyist I don't want code writing I want a solution to my answer which SO *is* for. I already have code it's just not having the desired effect. I'm looping through every single object I have and processing it, along with the labels into a single array. My problem is that each label is appended to the end of the array rather than in between. If you told me array_walk was the method I needed I'd gladly research and pull out the solution myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Chris I am simply moderating the site. This is not against you. All I simply think is that you should add the code you stated you have tried. Having us solve specific issues is a lot better then here is my data I want it to look like this. Do you see how that can seem like requesting code services?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136166/discussion-between-chris-and-nerdlyist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_keys(array_merge($aArr1, $aArr2, $aArr3)); 
sort($result, SORT_REGULAR );


[
    (int) 0 => 'Label 1',
    (int) 1 => 'Label 2',
    (int) 2 => 'Label 3.1',
    (int) 3 => 'Label 3.2',
    (int) 4 => 'Label 3.3',
    (int) 5 => 'Label 4',
    (int) 6 => 'Label 5',
    (int) 7 => 'Label 6'
]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but sort will sort the array alphabetically by default right? These labels are just for example, in reality these values can be anything.

Comment: The default sort is `SORT_REGULAR`, you can change that flag as you wish

Comment: thanks. Having thought about this I think the issue is primarily that my code needs refactoring and there are more efficient ways to be doing it. Given that this is a completely valid and good answer and in most cases would be the correct approach, I'm going to mark it as accepted.